# emacs org mode do not expand heading when pasted

Tags: org-mode

I often cut and paste folded top-level headings (only the heading is displayed, not its subcontent and tree).

When I do a paste, the heading is pasted unfolded - ie all subcontent and the tree is shown. After the paste, the current cursor point is at the bottom of the subcontent.

If I have eg 200 lines of subcontent, then I have to scroll back up to the heading to fold it.

Is there a setting in org mode to paste a heading and subcontent but not expand/unfold the subcontent?

Thanks ahead of time for any help......

Comment: You can navigate by heading: `C-c C-p` will take you to the previous heading. If the paste involved just a single heading, that's all that's needed. If there are more, you will need to do `C-c C-p` a few times to get there, but it's generally fast. The answer provides a few more generally applicable methods that are worth remembering, particularly the first one.

Comment: Thanks once again NickD for your input. This seems like a convenient way to do what I would like to do.

Answer (score 1):

Using Emacs functionality, you could either: 1) call `yank` with an argument, `C-u C-y`, that will leave point at the beginning of the yanked text; 2) call `yank` and then pop the mark, `C-y C-u C-SPC`, that would bring point back to the beginning of the yanked text after yanking.

Using Org functionality, you could use its specialized commands for the purpose: `org-cut-special` (bound by default to `C-c C-x C-w`) and `org-paste-special` (bound by default to `C-c C-x C-y`). This should carry around the folded state of your subtrees. Note that `org-paste-special` may promote/demote the yanked subtree, according to context. If that's not wanted, regular `org-yank` (`C-y`) should also deliver it folded, if it was killed as a subtree (that is, with `C-c C-x C-w`) to start with.

Comment: Thank you gusbrs for your input. I am not familiar with the terminology such as yank and killed, and so I will have to learn that (which I am happy to do) to understand your response.

Comment: "Yank" in emacs means the same thing as "paste" does in GUI environments. The function `yank` is bound to `C-y` by default. `C-u` is the "universal prefix argument": it basically calls the next function with a special argument that the function can interpret as it wants. So 1) in the answer says: if you press `C-y` alone, you yank ("paste") the text and that leaves you with the cursor at the end of the yanked text. But if you do the yank with the prefix argument (`C-u C-y`) then you are left with the cursor at the beginning of the yanked text.

Comment: Do `C-h f yank RET` to see the doc string of the function which describes this. See [Killing and Moving Text](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Killing.html#Killing) in the Emacs manual for all the gory details.

Comment: @NickD Thanks for clearing things for the OP. I presumed "emacs-lingo", and perhaps I shouldn't have.

Comment: It's impossible to know, so we do the best that we can.

Comment: BTW, feel free to incorporate any of that in your answer if you want. The trouble with comments is that sometimes they can disappear.

Comment: Well, the answer is correct, and thus useful to other people. It is just that I should have taken the hint from the use of "paste" that the OP required this extra step. And I thanked you, because it was kind of you to have it done, given the latter comment of the OP. I haven't been around much here of late, but I know you do. Do you think most users would also need it? If so, I'd be glad to incorporate it in the answer.

Comment: Yup, on rereading it, I think you are right.